# Is a good practice define an ID attribute in a class?

Tags: oop

I have an ID field in the database which is a primary key. Is it a good practice to define it in the class? I will need the key to perform updates and other operations.

I have this doubt because I'm not sure, but a professor said that it is not a good practice.

EDIT:

```
public class Pagina {

  private int id; //<--this is an good practice?
  private String urlOriginal;
  private String urlRedirected;
  private String content;
  private Link[] links;
  private Date updateDate;
  private Date visitDate;
  private boolean visitedLinks;
}
```

Comment: @Oli Any one who is in the database. I will edit the post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to my professor**, in the UML solution of the problem, the Id should not be defined because each object is unique and don't needs an identifier attribute to this, but after, depending on which technology used, in the final project, the Id is necessary and there are no problems in using it. This not violate the good practices.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is persisted to the DB using JPA then its mandatory. If not then its still pretty useful. Hard to think of an example when it could prove to be a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, **no**.

Unfortunately most ORM frameworks that exist today don't support the 
database's primary key transparently. [Grails](http://grails.org/) does as does the OODBMS [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), but ones like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) don't.

This means that you'll either have to bite the bullet and define the id in your domain class or write an additional layer to wrap your domain classes in to something that your RDBMS can talk to without exposing the persistence implementation to your business logic layer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, if you use a Map, it is often redundant to place the key in the value.  However, the cost is usually trivial, as it is here. If you think it is easier to model the data this way, that is what I would do. (Even if you don't have a framework which requires it)

Clarity is usually the most important thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If your model class persistable -- then it's mandatory to define some PK analog.
But it's not always should be named id -- in case of Page it could be it's url for example (but it`s not a good idea).

Does your professor argumentate it somehow?